# MVC jquery.dataTables Unable to get property 'className' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get `jquery.dataTables` plug in to work in MVC5. 
I have added everything(library and css) and included in my bundles correctly and can verify that all is there and it works by making a second table using straight html tags. That one shows and has the dataTables base functionality. But the table I am making dynamically gets the following error:

```
Unhandled exception at line 669, column 8 in .../Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js
Unable to get property 'className' of undefined or null reference.
```

I have verified that my table id is correct.

--Fixed

-- Not sure how this works. But I found the problem/solution accidentally. 
I'm going to submit this anyway in case what I found is useful.

The THead section had one empty cell. (a `<td></td>` pair) that made the `TBody` section not match in count of # of cells. It would work by either adding another empty Body cell or removing the THead cell. Clearly these two items have to match one for one.

Comment: Awesome!! This worked for me indirectly. I introspected and got that one comma(,) was there after the last statement of datatable property "aoColumns". All other browsers were taking it correct while the IE didn't.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any empty `<th>`, enough `<td>` to match the number of the `<th>` should be added. Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The table generated by the visual studio scaffolding does not has a 
`<thead>` or `<tbody>` tags.

The default structure of the generated table is:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>...</th>
      <th>...</th>
      <th></th>   <!-- the EMPTY header column -->
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
   </tr>
   .
   .
   .
   <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Note that the last header column is empty by default since in the child rows it has the C**RUD** commands:

> Edit | Details | Delete

For [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) to work, the `<thead>` is compulsory and `<tbody>` is optional. When you are going to add the `<thead>` tag, its better to add the `<tbody>` tag also just for readability/symmetry [IMHO].

With the current version of the DataTables (1.10.9), it working fine with **ONLY** adding the `<thead>` tags.

The minimum required structure is:

```
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>...</th>
         <th>...</th>
         <th></th>   <!-- it will work -->
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>   <!-- optional, just for readability -->
      <tr>
         <td>...</td>
         <td>...</td>
         <td>...</td>
      </tr>
      .
      .
      .
      <tr>
         <td>...</td>
         <td>...</td>
         <td>...</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Source:** Just re-tested all of these points.